# How can I remove duplicate subarrays from my multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-unique

I have an array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "test#4"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "C"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "C"
  ]
]
```

I want to get only the unique values:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "test#4"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "C"
  ]
]
```

What PHP function should I use?

I use `array_unique()`:

```
$group_array = [];
foreach ($private_group_devices as $i=>$group) {
    $group_array[$i]['name'] = $group['group_name'];
}
// dd($group_array);
dd(array_unique($group_array));
```

But I keep getting:

> Array to string conversion

Comment: Either `foreach` or `array_column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the [`SORT_REGULAR`](http://php.net/array-unique) flag into your `array_unique` call, as follows:

```
dd(array_unique($group_array, SORT_REGULAR));
```

By default, `array_unique` attempts to convert each item to a string (which doesn't quite work for arrays). Using `SORT_REGULAR` tells `array_unique` to compare items without converting their types.

Comment: Plus 1 for shorter than the one in the link. ;p

Comment: Either solution would work, and it actually appears that my answer is the same as [the second-highest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18373723/899126)! That being said, there is a caveat to using `array_unique` in this fashion; it is [not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#refsect1-function.array-unique-notes). It works, but there may be some hairiness depending on the situation.